# Where does Capistrano multistage (capistrano-ext) get stage parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I read capistrano multistage(capistrano-ext) source code.
But I couldn't found the statement of getting stage parameter from ARGV.

I use capistrano (2.5.13) and capistrano-ext (1.2.1).
I can't update version for a reason.

Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/ext/multistage.rb#L22 checks the first argument and if it's a valid stage will set the stage.

Comment: Thanks.but sorry, I didn't write the version. I use capistrano (2.5.13) and capistrano-ext (1.2.1). I can't update version for a reason.